# Error In Import: Attribute doesn't belong to attribute_set in row(s)

Tags: magento-2.1, importexport, firegento-extendedimport2

I'm trying to import configurable product in magento 2 by CSV. using firegento extension.

For simple product, It is working fine. But for the configurable product it fails.

eg: in CSV file

Simple product row: `attribute_set_code = Stem` And `steerer_diameter = 1-1/8"`

Configurable Product Row: `attribute_set_code = Stem` And `steerer_diameter =''"`

So in this case Import show error for configurable product:

```
1: Begin data validation
2: Data validation failed. Please fix the following errors and upload the file again.
3: Attribute steerer_diameter doesn't belong to attribute_set in row(s): 1
4: Broken product SKU VARPRS008 in row(s): 1
5: Checked rows: 1, checked entities: 1, invalid rows: 1, total errors: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because attribute was created as text field and for configurable product, the attribute field should be dropdown / text swatches. (not text field)